# parsing a json file with awk or sed by dividing contents into lines based on start and end match

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a `.json` file which I need to parse:

```
 {
    "schemaVersion":16,
    "addons":[
      {"id":"testpilot@labs.mozilla.com","syncGUID":"pc9SmMiK6Peu","location":"app-profile","version":"1.2.3.1-signed","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":"chrome://testpilot/skin/testpilot_32x32.png","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Test Pilot","description":"Help make Firefox better by running user studies.","creator":"Mozilla Corporation","homepageURL":"http://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/"},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/testpilot@labs.mozilla.com.xpi","installDate":1431796864000,"updateDate":1432784122000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":1278820,"sourceURI":"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/13661/test_pilot-1.2.3-fx.xpi?filehash=sha256%3A813e3080c355e98091fa321529cf3949739ef3a1497a4b45a3b5244aee443fac","releaseNotesURI":"https://addons.mozilla.org/versions/updateInfo/1501117/en-US/","softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.5","maxVersion":"17.0a1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false},
      {"id":"dreditor@dreditor.org","syncGUID":"Lu-OEFQCHDuJ","location":"app-profile","version":"1.2.14","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Dreditor","description":"An extension for Drupal.org that enhances user experience and functionality. Original author: Daniel F. Kudwien (sun).","creator":"Mark Carver","homepageURL":"https://dreditor.org"},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/dreditor@dreditor.org.xpi","installDate":1432790689000,"updateDate":1432790689000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"size":124907,"sourceURI":"https://dreditor.org/dreditor.xpi?1.2.14","releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"21.0","maxVersion":"29.0a1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false},
      {"id":"en-US@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org","syncGUID":"n8s_OF7ZCuw1","location":"app-profile","version":"7.0.1","type":"dictionary","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"United States English Spellchecker","description":"English United States (en-US) Spellchecker","creator":"Giuliano Masseroni","homepageURL":"https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3497","contributors":["Kevin Atkinson","Geoff Kuenning"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/en-US@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org","installDate":1433038761000,"updateDate":1433038761000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"size":701806,"sourceURI":"https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/3497/addon-3497-latest.xpi?src=dp-btn-primary","releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"17.0","maxVersion":"42.0"},{"id":"{3550f703-e582-4d05-9a08-453d09bdfdc6}","minVersion":"5.0","maxVersion":"23.0"},{"id":"{92650c4d-4b8e-4d2a-b7eb-24ecf4f6b63a}","minVersion":"2.0","maxVersion":"2.20"}],"targetPlatforms":[]},
      {"id":"it-IT@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org","syncGUID":"0HLJG3tK5S0H","location":"app-profile","version":"3.4.0","type":"dictionary","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Italian dictionary","description":"Italian dictionary based on version 3.4.0 (2013-09-05) of the Italian dictionary created by project PLIO.","creator":"Francesco Lodolo","homepageURL":"http://www.mozillaitalia.org"},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/it-IT@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org","installDate":1433038989000,"updateDate":1433038989000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"size":1412342,"sourceURI":"https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/3053/platform:3/addon-3053-latest.xpi?src=dp-btn-primary","releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[{"locales":["it"],"name":"Dizionario italiano","description":"Dizionario italiano basato sulla versione 3.4.0 (2013-09-05) del dizionario realizzato dal progetto PLIO.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null}],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"18.0a1","maxVersion":"41.0"},{"id":"{3550f703-e582-4d05-9a08-453d09bdfdc6}","minVersion":"18.0a1","maxVersion":"34.0"},{"id":"{92650c4d-4b8e-4d2a-b7eb-24ecf4f6b63a}","minVersion":"2.7a1","maxVersion":"2.31"},{"id":"{aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110}","minVersion":"18.0a1","maxVersion":"34.0"},"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":"18.0a1","maxVersion":"34.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[]},
      {"id":"onepassword4@agilebits.com","syncGUID":"fqAFQIuqP6rc","location":"app-profile","version":"4.4.2","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":"https://d13itkw33a7sus.cloudfront.net/dist/1P/ext/autoupdate_firefox4.xml","updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"1Password","description":"Password and identity manager for Mac, Windows, iOS and Android.","creator":"AgileBits Inc","homepageURL":"https://agilebits.com/onepassword"},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/onepassword4@agilebits.com.xpi","installDate":1431759097000,"updateDate":1438291043000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"size":248521,"sourceURI":"https://d13itkw33a7sus.cloudfront.net/dist/1P/ext/1Password-4.4.2.xpi","releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"24.0","maxVersion":"27.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false},
      {"id":"langpack-en-US@firefox.mozilla.org","syncGUID":"hbdMIPDTjJjU","location":"app-profile","version":"39.0","type":"locale","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"English (US) Language Pack","description":null,"creator":"mozilla.org","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/langpack-en-US@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi","installDate":1433038780000,"updateDate":1438297982000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"size":1107183,"sourceURI":"https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/407142/english_us_language_pack-39.0-fx.xpi?filehash=sha256%3Ae970523c118125330029522253119290be0c3fae810304b6f8851d5b1a08bb2a","releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"39.0","maxVersion":"39.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[]},
      {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"4aQXjLIYT8-y","location":"app-global","version":"39.0.3","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1428098726000,"updateDate":1439001657000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":3175,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"39.0.3","maxVersion":"39.0.3"}],"targetPlatforms":[]},{"id":"{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92}","syncGUID":"mtfF_fBR6ym-","location":"app-system-local","version":"2.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee SiteAdvisor","description":null,"creator":"McAfee Inc.","homepageURL":"http://www.siteadvisor.com/"},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92}","installDate":1417806531000,"updateDate":1417806531000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":18013,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"4.0","maxVersion":"15.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false}
    ]
}
```

I need to take each `{"id":` line from the `"addons"` section and get the `"version":`, "name": under `"defaultLocale"` and `"descriptor":` sections.

I need the same to be done in only `awk` or `sed` (basically any standard linux commands or a combination of these). I'll not be able to use `jq` or any other tools to parse the `.json` file.

Please help

Comment: Why don't you use `jq` to parse the JSON?

Comment: Start with `jq -r .addons[].id input-file`

Comment: If you post a [mcve] (note: **Minimal**) instead of text that's about 2,000 characters wide with the relevant constructs buried deep inside it we might be able to help you. Also post the expected output, not just the input, plus show what you've tried so far. State whether or not the "name" and "version" tags exist in blocks other than inside "defaultLocale" and "descriptor" sections and do those sections appear other than on the same line as the "id" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear wrt requirements, the lines in the example are WAY too long to wade through trying to find the context for the strings you're interested in, and you haven't shown us the expected output so there's not much we can do to help but here's a start that you can hopefully adapt to do whatever it is you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/"(version|name)":("[^"]*"|[^,}]+)/) ) {
        print NR, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
4 "version":"1.2.3.1-signed"
4 "name":"Test Pilot"
5 "version":"1.2.14"
5 "name":"Dreditor"
6 "version":"7.0.1"
6 "name":"United States English Spellchecker"
7 "version":"3.4.0"
7 "name":"Italian dictionary"
7 "name":"Dizionario italiano"
8 "version":"4.4.2"
8 "name":"1Password"
9 "version":"39.0"
9 "name":"English (US) Language Pack"
10 "version":"39.0.3"
10 "name":"Default"
10 "version":"2.0"
10 "name":"McAfee SiteAdvisor"
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/"defaultLocale":{[^{}]+}|"descriptor":("[^"]*"|[^,}]+)/) ) {
        sect = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        print NR, sect
        while ( match(sect,/"(version|name)":("[^"]*"|[^,}]+)/) ) {
            print "\t" substr(sect,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            sect = substr(sect,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file



4 "defaultLocale":{"name":"Test Pilot","description":"Help make Firefox better by running user studies.","creator":"Mozilla Corporation","homepageURL":"http://testpilot.mozillalabs.com/"}
        "name":"Test Pilot"
4 "descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/testpilot@labs.mozilla.com.xpi"

5 "defaultLocale":{"name":"Dreditor","description":"An extension for Drupal.org that enhances user experience and functionality. Original author: Daniel F. Kudwien (sun).","creator":"Mark Carver","homepageURL":"https://dreditor.org"}
        "name":"Dreditor"
5 "descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/dreditor@dreditor.org.xpi"

6 "defaultLocale":{"name":"United States English Spellchecker","description":"English United States (en-US) Spellchecker","creator":"Giuliano Masseroni","homepageURL":"https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3497","contributors":["Kevin Atkinson","Geoff Kuenning"]}
        "name":"United States English Spellchecker"
6 "descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/en-US@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org"

7 "defaultLocale":{"name":"Italian dictionary","description":"Italian dictionary based on version 3.4.0 (2013-09-05) of the Italian dictionary created by project PLIO.","creator":"Francesco Lodolo","homepageURL":"http://www.mozillaitalia.org"}
        "name":"Italian dictionary"
7 "descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/it-IT@dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org"

8 "defaultLocale":{"name":"1Password","description":"Password and identity manager for Mac, Windows, iOS and Android.","creator":"AgileBits Inc","homepageURL":"https://agilebits.com/onepassword"}
        "name":"1Password"
8 "descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/onepassword4@agilebits.com.xpi"

9 "defaultLocale":{"name":"English (US) Language Pack","description":null,"creator":"mozilla.org","homepageURL":null}
        "name":"English (US) Language Pack"
9 "descriptor":"/Users/kiamlaluno/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/a9wsbury.default/extensions/langpack-en-US@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi"

10 "defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]}
        "name":"Default"
10 "descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}"
10 "defaultLocale":{"name":"McAfee SiteAdvisor","description":null,"creator":"McAfee Inc.","homepageURL":"http://www.siteadvisor.com/"}
        "name":"McAfee SiteAdvisor"
10 "descriptor":"/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92}"
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box. Note that it does what it does with your posted sample input only, don't expect it to work robustly for JSON in general.

Comment: The output comes as `"version":"v1.1"\n"name":"Dict"\n"descriptor":"/directory/path"`. How can I change the output to `Dict|v1.1|/directory/path` ?. So basically instead of having the context names, just their values with delimiter as `|` and no quotes or other characters. NOTE: The `\n` I've used is just to make you understand that the ouput is broken in different lines.

Comment: Made some minimal changes in your script and the output is as in my above comment. My final script: 
`{
        while ( match($0,/"defaultLocale":{[^{}]+}|"(descriptor|version)":("[^"]*"|[^,}]+)/) ) {
            sect = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
            $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            while ( match(sect,/"(name|version|descriptor)":("[^"]*"|[^,}]+)/) ) {
                print substr(sect,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                sect = substr(sect,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

`jq` should get you a long way:

```
# some JSON resembling yours
JSON='{"schemaVersion":16, "addons":[{"id": "id_1"}, {"id": "id_2"}, {"id": "id_3"}]}'
jq -r '.addons[].id' <<< $JSON
```

which gives:

```
id_1
id_2
id_3
```

Comment: `-r` is probably useful here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a tool specialized for `json` processing (like `jq` as suggested in the comments) if you are going to parse a more complicated `json`.

However, if your `json` has the exact same format as mentioned, you may filter it as a normal text file using `sed` as follows.

```
sed '0,/"id"/ d; /}/,/"id"/ d;s/\s*//' input.txt
```

Output:

```
//data 1    # suffixed with a number to indicate different lines
//data 2
//data 3
//data 4
```

Comment: I thought I was clear in my question, that I need a solution either in `awk` or `sed` in bash. I am in a very limited Linux development environment, and don't have the luxury to try out `jq` tool for parsing json files.

Comment: I added the suggestion on top as that would be the proper way to parse a `json` (and before you edited the question saying you are unable to use `jq`). But my answer is based on `sed` as you've tagged it.